# Spring security: SQL [select username,password from user where username=?]; Column Index out of range, 3 > 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use the spring security in my spring boot application. I have the below method to authenticate the users:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,sys_role "
                                    + " FROM user join user_sys_role on user.id=user_sys_role.user_id"
                                    + " where username=?");

}
```

But it fails when i send a `post` request to it, and when i debug the app it provides the error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select username,password from user where username=?]; Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2.
```

**How can i fix it?**

it seems that, there is a problem in

```
 .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password from user where username=?")
```

Comment: The query requires 3 column to be returned `username`,`password` and `enabled` to be exact.

Comment: thanks for pointer